# Direct links to the anchors do not work using jQuery Scrollto.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site where I am using the jQuery scrollTo.js script to navigate back and forth within the main page of the site.

http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com

The anchor links in the main nav work fine, however if you try to go to a page directly it takes you to the wrong anchor.

Click on this link: http://new-had.herrmanneasyeditdemo.com/#services

You will see that it does not take you directly to the services section. It actually takes you to the bottom of the "All in a Day’s Work" section.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Works perfectly fine in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, but its not working in Firefox.

Comment: Man, why use plugins when you can write it yourself? Take a look here, I just wrote it: https://jsfiddle.net/95uvt0a0/1/. 15 lines of jQuery. Hope it helps :)